# Python pickle calls cPickle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, pickle

I am new to Python. I am adapting someone else's code from Python 2.X to 3.5. The code loads a file via cPickle. I changed all "cPickle" occurrences to "pickle" as I understand pickle superceded cPickle in 3.5. I get this execution error:

```
NameError: name 'cPickle' is not defined
```

Pertinent code:

```
import pickle
import gzip
...
def load_data():
    f = gzip.open('../data/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = pickle.load(f, fix_imports=True)
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)
```

The error occurs in the `pickle.load` line when `load_data()` is called by another function. However, a) neither `cPickle` or `cpickle` no longer appear in any source files anywhere in the project (searched globally) and b) the error does not occur if I run the lines within `load_data()` individually in the Python shell (however, I do get another data format error). Is `pickle` calling `cPickle`, and if so how do I stop it?

Shell:
Python 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 20 2015, 14:39:26) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin

IDE: IntelliJ 15.0.1, Python 3.5.0, anaconda

Unclear how to proceed. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check for `.pyc` files and remove them. They might be out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's looking like the pickled data that you're trying to load was generated by a version of the program that was running on Python 2.7. The data is what contains the references to `cPickle`.

The problem is that Pickle, as a serialization format, assumes that your standard library (and to a lesser extent your code) won't change layout between serialization and deserialization. Which it did -- a lot -- between Python 2 and 3. And when that happens, Pickle has no path for migration.

Do you have access to the program that generated `mnist.pkl.gz`? If so, port it to Python 3 and re-run it to regenerate a Python 3-compatible version of the file.

If not, you'll have to write a Python 2 program that loads that file and exports it to a format that can be loaded from Python 3 (depending on the shape of your data, JSON and CSV are popular choices), then write a Python 3 program that loads that format then dumps it as Python 3 pickle. You can then load that Pickle file from your original program.

Of course, what you should *really* do is stop at the point where you have ability to load the exported format from Python 3 -- and use the aforementioned format as your actual, long-term storage format.

Using Pickle for anything other than short-term serialization between *trusted* programs (loading Pickle is equivalent to running arbitrary code in your Python VM) is something you should actively avoid, among other things because of the exact case you find yourself in.

Comment: Thanks Max. I do not have access to the code that generated the pickled data files but I can try running under Python 2.7 to read them.

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.6, and tried everything: import pickle as cPickle, import pickle, import _pickle as cPickle but still having the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cPickle' "

Comment: @pari That has nothing to do with this question, but in Python 3 there is no `cPickle` anymore. Just use `import pickle` (or even better, *don't* use Pickle, it's still a slow, insecure, *bad* serialization format -- try JSON instead).

Answer (score 7):

Actually, if you have pickled objects from `python2.x`, then generally can be read by `python3.x`.  Also, if you have pickled objects from `python3.x`, they generally can be read by `python2.x`, but only if they were dumped with a `protocol` set to `2` or less.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep  2 2015, 17:36:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> import math
>>> y = math.sin
>>>     
>>> import pickle 
>>> f = open('foo.pik', 'w') 
>>> pickle.dump(x, f)
>>> pickle.dump(y, f)
>>> f.close()
>>> 
dude@hilbert>$ python3.5
Python 3.5.0 (default, Sep 15 2015, 23:57:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('foo.pik', 'rb') as f:
...   x = pickle.load(f)
...   y = pickle.load(f)
... 
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> y
<built-in function sin>
```

Also, if you are looking for `cPickle`, it's now `_pickle`, not `pickle`.

```
>>> import _pickle
>>> _pickle
<module '_pickle' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-35m-darwin.so'>
>>>
```

You also asked how to stop `pickle` from using the built-in (C++) version. You can do this by using `_dump` and `_load`, or the `_Pickler` class if you like to work with the class objects.  Confused?  The old `cPickle` is now `_pickle`, however `dump`, `load`, `dumps`, and `loads` all point to `_pickle`… while `_dump`, `_load`, `_dumps`, and `_loads` point to the pure python version.  For instance:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> # _dumps is a python function
>>> pickle._dumps
<function _dumps at 0x109c836a8>
>>> # dumps is a built-in (C++)
>>> pickle.dumps
<built-in function dumps>
>>> # the Pickler points to _pickle (C++)
>>> pickle.Pickler 
<class '_pickle.Pickler'>
>>> # the _Pickler points to pickle (pure python)
>>> pickle._Pickler
<class 'pickle._Pickler'>
>>>
```

So if you don't want to use the built-in version, then you can use `pickle._loads` and the like.

Answer (score 4):

In Anaconda Python3.5 :
one can access cPickle as

```
import _pickle as cPickle
```

credits to [Mike McKerns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2379433/mike-mckerns)

Answer (score 0):

This bypasses the technical issues, but there might be a py3 version of that file named mnist_py3k.pkl.gz If so, try opening that file instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a code in github that does it: https://gist.github.com/rebeccabilbro/2c7bb4d1acfbcdcf9156e7b9b7577cba

I have tried it and it worked. You just need to specify the encoding, in this case it is 'latin1':

```
pickle.load(open('mnist.pkl','rb'), encoding = 'latin1')
```